# Cakephp Set::sort()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

im using cakephp 1.3. Im trying to sort an array using Set::sort() function but is not working.. any idea on how to do this? below is the array im using.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Group] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Team A
                )

            [Members] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => George
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => C
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Hall
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => A
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Mike
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => B
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

im sorting the array using this :

```
$data = Set::sort($data, '{n}.Members.{n}.Code.name', 'asc');
```

im expecting an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Group] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Team A
                )

            [Members] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Hall
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => A
                                )

                        )


                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Mike
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => B
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => George
                            [Code] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => C
                                )

                        )


                )

        )
```

The sorting does not take in effect.how can i do this? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using only `Set::sort()` its no doable. You can you this:

```
    $result =  array();
    foreach($a as $arr) {
        $res = Set::sort($arr['Member'], '{n}.Code.name', 'asc');
        $result[] = array(
                    'Group' => $arr['Group'],
                    'Member' => $res
                );            
    }
    pr($result);
```